# Search for and view a file deleted from the repo

Tags: git, search, version-control

I'm working on a project in git, and I know that at some time in the past (long before I had the code) there existed a file called `exec.js`.
I want to view the contents of this file. 
I know which repository used to contain this file, but I don't know the exact path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use wildcard characters in `git log`:

```
git log -- *exec.js
```

will give you all log messages when any file called `exec.js` was modified.

Once you find the deleting commit (say `A`), you could

```
git checkout A -- *exec.js
```

This will bring you the last version of `exec.js`.

If you want to view the full history of `exec.js`, you could use `gitk`:

```
gitk -- *exec.js
```

This will show you all the modifications again. If you're particularly interested in one commit, you could right click the file in the `gitk` dialog and then select **external diff tool**. This will open the external diff tool with the **full** files, not only the patches.

Comment: You can also do a **git diff *revision-before-delete* -- *filepath*** to see the full content of the file.  (It will have the "-" in front of each line, since each line was deleted from the file.)

Answer (score 1):

You can search for that particular file inside log history using -

If you don't have filepath then

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep filename
```

If you have filepath then you can use -

```
git log -- filepath
git log -n 1 -- filepath
```

and once you get the revision you can checkout that particular revision to get that file

Comment: You didn't read the question, did you? They said they **don't know** the path. This is path filter. It requires the path. It's therefore useless.

Comment: I don't know the path and I didn't have the code when the file was deleted.

Comment: @JanHudec yes me ..but of-course he must be having git repository path. user429400 don't you?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to list a deleted file's full name and its contents in one or two commands. However, here's an alias to get you started:

```
$ git config --global alias.find-deleted-file '!f() { for c in `git rev-list HEAD`; do for fnm in `git diff-tree -r --diff-filter=D --name-only $c | grep -P ".*/$1"` ; do echo "$c $fnm" ; git show $c^:$fnm ; echo "" ; done ; done ; } ; f'
```

This will make available a Git `find-deleted-file` alias that will search for a deleted file (using [`diff-tree`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree)) with the provided file name pattern (pattern matching provided by [`grep -P`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)), displaying the commit the file was deleted, the file's full name and its content before it was deleted.

Using the following example repository history:

```
$ git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline --name-only
* 3f3cba1 (HEAD, master) I
I
* 4c8b369 H
E/H
* a008343 rm F
E/F
* 525a127 FG
E/F
E/G
* 3a10f93 initial
A
B
C
D
E/F
```

You would search for the deleted `F` file using:

```
$ git find-deleted-file F
a008343eec91fe917078209d44ae93ee72fc5acb E/F
F
```